# How to deal with very large objects?

Tags: java, eofexception

I am dealing with large Java object(single object may be as big as 1GB).When I try trasfering objects larger than 104004 KB it is throwing EOFException. Is it because my object is too large for the ObjectInputStream to hold or is there any other reason. What could be solution of this problem?

Comment: Why are you operating on objects of such size? Can't you split them into many smaller objects? You could avoid many problems, like having to restart data transfer of the whole thing in case of error.

Comment: How did they get this large? An object graph with millions of objects, or huge arrays?

Comment: Who on earth serialized a Java object into a 1 GB file? Maybe you should rethink the architecture of your system.

Comment: Are you getting EOF while writing, or while reading (which is more common)?

Comment: I am executing a Machine learning (NLP) algorithm. For that I have to compute something considering many trainging example simultaneously thus the objects become large. (I have total dataset of 15 GB).

Comment: @Pelit I am getting it while reading an object throught object stream.

Comment: Most likely your problem is unrelated to the actual object size and the written data is corrupted in some way, again most likely incompletely written from the start. Check which kind of object is supposed to deserialize when the EoF happens, then check that types serialization/deserialization.